# Cardinality of the set $S$ where $S=\{T:\Bbb{R}^3\to \Bbb{R}^3\mid T \text{ is a linear transformation with } T(1,0,1)=(1,2,3), T(1,2,3)=(1,0,1)\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Let $S=\{\,T\colon \mathbb{R}^3\to \mathbb{R}^3\mid T \text{ is a linear transformation with } T(1,0,1)=(1,2,3), T(1,2,3)=(1,0,1)\,\}$. Then $S$ is

A. a singleton set

B. a finite set containing more than one element

C. a countably infinite set

D. an uncountable set

I can see that there are several such matrices $T$ which will satisfy the given conditions of the set $S$. And I can produce them by hit and trial. But I don't know how to proceed further.

Answer (score 0):

A linear transform is determined by its values on a basis. The vectors $(1,0,1)$ and $(1,2,3)$ are linearly independent, hence can be extended to a basis. As we can prescribe the first two values as given and the third arbitrarily (with a choice from all of $\Bbb R^3$), $S$ is uncountable.

Comment: Your words "A linear transform is determined by its values on a basis.". Can you please elaborate on this?

Answer (score 0):

$T$ is a linear map from $\mathbb R^3$ to $\mathbb R^3$. You need one more vector to extend $\{(1,0,1),(1,2,3)\}$ into a basis of $\mathbb R^3$. This vector can be chosen in uncountably many ways and hence $T$ can be chosen in uncountably many ways.